# Odoo 12: How to disable past dates with datepicker?

Tags: datepicker, odoo

How can I use datepicker in a Date field?
I try to disable past dates like that:

```
<field class="delivery_date" name="delivery_date" options="{'datepicker':{'minDate': 0}}"/>
```

But past dates are shown nevertheless.
It seems as if the options-tag is not parsed at all. I used the debugger to get an overview what happens in addons/web/static/src/js/fields/basic_fields.js (where datepicker is initialized) but there are no options declared.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

That's my field definition

```
delivery_date = fields.Date(string='Delivery Date', help="Date on which sales order is delivered.", default=_get_default_delivery_date)
```

The default-method sets the date to the day after tomorrow.

My view declaration is above. That's all I have.

I expected that the datepicker is invoked as soon as I use it in "options"-attribute.

When I enter my website the datepicker is shown, when I click on that date-field, but the past dates are not disabled..

Comment: You want to empty the date fields in all the modules?@tisq

Comment: @Navi, no I would like to disable past dates in the view. So that the user can only select dates in the future.

Comment: Can you post it with an example@tisq

Comment: @Navi, I posted my field definitions above. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple modules, but nothing works for me in js Odoo 14

```
@api.model
def fields_view_get(self, view_id=None, view_type='form', toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    res = super(AccountInvoice, self).fields_view_get(view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)
    if view_type == 'form':
        doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
        for node in doc.xpath("//field[@name='date_invoice']"):
            node.set('options', "{'datepicker': {'minDate': '%sT23:59:59'}}" % fields.Date.today().strftime(DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT))
        res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)
    return res
```

Try this, This may help you